# resources for building dynamic drop down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

this is a beginner question- I can't seem to find any good resources explaining how to build a dynamic drop down menu. This is the basic scenario:

I have a list of Assets HABTM to Projects

I want to display a list of Assets, each with the Projects it is assigned to and "Add to project" drop down with the list of projects that Asset can be assigned to. Ideally it'd be ajax based so the used doesnt have to leave the page.

I find it difficult to start, so I'd appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Railscasts has a good episode...it's a revised one so it requires membership but if you are doing any Rails development a membership is a wise investment.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised